# The encoding 'UTF-8' is not supported by the Java runtime

Tags: java, linux, unicode

Whenever I start our Apache Felix (OSGi) based application under SUN Java ( build 1.6.0_10-rc2-b32 and other 1.6.x builds) I see the following message output on the console (usually under Ubuntu 8.4):

> Warning:  The encoding 'UTF-8' is not supported by the Java runtime.

I've seen this message display occasionally when running both Tomcat and Resin as well.  If java supports unicode and UTF-8, what causes this message?  I've yet to find any reference, or answer to this anywhere else.

Comment: whose implementation of java is this ? which version of java ? which java apps (did you write them or are they an open source app we know of) ?

Comment: Strange. UTF-8 is a required encoding. No one should release a Java runtime that doesn't include UTF-8 and US-ASCII.

Comment: Could it be something lacking in the underlying OS?

Comment: I got the same message. Different environment. I found that it was coming from the transform method of Transformer when the implementation of Transformer is com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.

Comment: No one should be using an RC build on a production system either :)

Comment: I just got the same error message when starting PyCharm 3.1.3.  Not sure it has any negative consequences while running the IDE though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According [the documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) "Every implementation of the Java platform is required to support the following standard charsets... US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-16."  So I doubt that Sun have released a build without UTF-8 support.

The actual error message appears to be from [here](http://www.jdocs.com/page/AjaxSourceCode?oid=10701), which is part of the Xerces XML parser.  I imagine it is the XML parser where the problem is occurring.

Comment: The problem in my instance arose from the usage of OSGi and class-loader visibility.  Multiple bundles instantiated the Xerces XML parser, but failed to find character set definitions as those resources were not visible.

Comment: Please give the packages that were not visible.  Which packages did you have to make visible?

Comment: If this is solution, how it solved the problem? Could you please specify what you have done? The problem occures in Fuse ESB 4.4 in logging system.

Comment: Yep, I can attest this comes from Xerces... but I can't find any real fix or workaround.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following program:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TestCharset {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

If this throws an exception, then there is something wrong with your JDK.
If it prints "UTF-8" then your JDK is OK, and your application is doing something odd.

If that's the case, run your app under the debugger, and put a breakpoint in http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/XML/xalan/org/apache/xml/serializer/ToStream.java.htm --that's the place this warning is produced, and step to see why Xalan can't find the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably someone put a catch() expecting to have only unsupported encoding exceptions, so he used the appropriate message. But he has used too wide exception specification (e.g. catch( Exception ex ) ), so when at runtime he's got something else (non-valid XML, NPE, ... ) the message became misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different (stable release) JVM. I had this problem once and it turned out that the machine was running a beta version JVM that indeed did not support UTF-8, contrary to the requirement in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "UTF8", without the dash.

Comment: Given Dan Dyer's answer, I don't think this is the case. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Michael is correct - sort of.  The JDK sources have mixed UTF8 and UTF-8 references in the various NIO, NIO2, and normal IO packages.  Quite awful really.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this message when using a Transformer, try to specify the TransformerFactory:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3389479/1092788)

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported in Apache Jira and jboss developer, it appears to be a known issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-1958

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/246660