# How to select saxon TransformerFactory in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, sax, xslt-2.0

In my web application I need to use Saxon TransformerFactory in order to use XSLT 2.0 but I can't use setProperty method because I don't have this right on the web server and there is a Security Manager.

So I have read that it should be possible to do this:

> Use the Services API (as detailed in the JAR specification), if available, to determine the classname. The Services API will look for a classname in the file META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory in jars available to the runtime.

I found this file in WEB-INF/lib/saxon9.jar but when I istantiate a TransformerFactory, the default factory is always selected instead of a Saxon factory.

How can I select Saxon Transformer Factory?

Thanks

Comment: A summary of all approaches below (and more) can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314604/how-to-set-saxon-as-the-xslt-processor-in-java

Answer (score 28):

The proper way to do this is by specifying the factory class when getting a new TransformerFactory.

I dont think calling a specific factory implementation will work - I believe the default system transformer might still be returned (at least thats what happened when I had xalan and saxon in the classpath).

example:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);
```

or for saxon

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl",null);
```

Javadocs:

> Obtain a new instance of a
>   TransformerFactory from factory class
>   name. This function is useful when
>   there are multiple providers in the
>   classpath. It gives more control to
>   the application as it can specify
>   which provider should be loaded. Once
>   an application has obtained a
>   reference to a TransformerFactory it
>   can use the factory to configure and
>   obtain transformer instances.

Comment: This works as of Java v6 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html vs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html)

Comment: This doesn't work with the Oracle Fusion Middleware 11.1.1.5.0 release as it uses older implementations within it's client jar files.

Answer (score 14):

Can you try by setting the system property in your code like

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory", "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

do this before getting an instance of TransformerFactory.

Note: this will force all the webapps on your Tomcat to use saxon - so you have to make sure any other webapps which were using the default are okay.

Answer (score 10):

Create file `META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` with content: `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`. That's it.

Comment: This did not work for me. I used the main META-INF directory of my webapp. Do I need to use a different one?

Answer (score 5):

If your application really requires saxon and won't work with another processor then it would probably be fine to instantiate the saxon TransformerFactory directly using `new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`