# Tomcat web app - specify TransformerFactoryImpl class doesn't work

Tags: java, tomcat, xslt, saxon

I need to use an xsl transformation inside a webapp and I decided to use saxon for the xml implementation. I included saxon(version 9.1) in the pom.xml as dependency. But I still keep getting this error - Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found

I found this thread, 
[How to select saxon TransformerFactory in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968190/how-to-select-saxon-transformerfactory-in-java)

and did all that was recommended, setting property, specifying a service file with saxon implementation class. For flexibility reasons, I can't directly create an instance of TransformerFactoryImpl. So, do I have any other choice left?

Thanks in advance,

Edit: This is the stack trace of the error -

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:108)
com.mondeca.sesame.toolkit.repository.XMLtoRDFDataInjector.injectData(XMLtoRDFDataInjector.java:83)
com.mondeca.sesame.toolkit.repository.LocalMemoryRepositoryProvider.init(LocalMemoryRepositoryProvider.java:105)
org.datalift.modules.base.XmlConverter.applyXslTransformation(XmlConverter.java:192)
org.datalift.modules.base.XmlConverter.transformData(XmlConverter.java:204)
org.datalift.modules.base.XmlConverter.transformData(XmlConverter.java:174)
org.datalift.modules.base.XmlConverter.loadSourceData(XmlConverter.java:149)
```

From which it's clear that it can't find saxon. But I simply don't understand why! I can see that its packaged in the jar file too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this would be useful for someone looking for a solution. I solved it a long time ago, but I forgot to update it here. Basically tomcat will try and over ride any XML implementations with it's own implementations. The tomcat I was using(must be 6.0.23) didn't contain the latest XML APIs to deal with XSLT transformations(I needed APIs which could handle XSLT2). Actually tomcat has a bit of strange behaviour here, it doesn't load classes from classpath first but tries to load classes from it's own libraries(which inturn might contain all required java classes), which is not a natural order of loading classes. So, specifying in the manifest file wouldn't help. On the other hand we can over ride this by specifying as an option while starting the server. Use this option as server arg

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS
```

For more information, tomcat [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) on this issue

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding Saxon JAR to the CLASSPATH and load Saxon using:

```
TransformerFactory transFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

Comment: As I mentioned above "For flexibility reasons, I can't directly create an instance of TransformerFactory" This code is in the plugin and creating an instance of TransformerFactory is(was) the work of the platform.