# How to set Saxon as the Xslt processor in Java?

Tags: java, xslt, sax

This is a simple question, but one I cannot find the answer to. I have an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that I'm trying to process in Java.  It relies on XSL elements from Saxon.

My current class works fine with simple XSLT 1.0, but I'm getting errors about unrecognized elements with my 2.0 XSLT built with Saxon.

I cannot figure out how to tell Java to use Saxon as the processor.  I'm using javax.xml.transform in my class.  Is this a property I can set?  What do I set it to?
Thanks!

**Edited**
I figured out how to set the property to use Saxon, but now I'm getting this error.

```
Provider net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
```

How do I include Saxon in my application?

Comment: Found the problem. I needed to add my Saxon jar to the classpath. I thought it was included with Java.

Comment: As well as having the Saxon JAR on the classpath I would recommend instantiating it explicitly: if your code will only work with Saxon, then use "new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()" rather than relying on the JAXP classpath search to ensure that it's definitely Saxon that's loaded (and to avoid the cost of the classpath search)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this (in order of lookup precedence):

### Direct Instantiation

Explicitly instantiate the [Saxon factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXTransformerFactory.html?is-external=true) (with a nod to Michael's comment above):

```
TransformerFactory fact = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()
```

*This approach means that your code is locked into using Saxon at compile time. This can be seen as an advantage (no risk of it running with the wrong processor) or a disadvantage (no opportunity to configure a different processor at execution time - not even Saxon Enterprise Edition).*

For Saxon-PE, substitute `com.saxonica.config.ProfessionalTransformerFactory`. For Saxon-EE, substitute `com.saxonica.config.EnterpriseTransformerFactory`.

### Specify Class Name

Specify the factory class when constructing it:

```
TransformerFactory fact = TransformerFactory.newInstance(
        "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
```

Note: [available as of Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29). The [Java 5 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) does not have this method.

*This approach allows you to choose the processor at execution time, while still avoiding the costs and risks of a classpath search. For example, your application could provide some configuration mechanism to allow it to run with different Saxon editions by choosing between the various Saxon factory classes.*

### Use System Property

Set the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` system property before creating an instance:

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",    
        "net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl");
```

Or on the command line (line broken for readability):

```
java -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=
        net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl YourApp
```

*This approach has the disadvantage that system properties affect the whole Java VM. Setting this property to select Saxon could mean that some other module in the application, which you might not even know about, starts using Saxon instead of Xalan, and that module could fail as a result if it uses Xalan-specific XSLT constructs.*

### Use Properties File

Create the following file:

```
JRE/lib/jaxp.properties
```

With the following contents:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

*This approach has similar consequences to using the system property.*

### Service Loader

Create the following file in any JAR on the CLASSPATH:

```
META-INF/services/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory
```

With the following contents:

```
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl
```

*This approach has the disadvantage that a small change to the classpath could cause the application to run with a different XSLT engine, perhaps one that the application has never been tested with.*

### Platform Default

If none of the above are done, then the platform default `TransformerFactory` instance will be loaded. A friendly description of this plugability layer can be found [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=3#plug_layer).

*Note that 'platform' here means the Java VM, not the hardware or operating system that it is running on. For all current known Java VMs, the platform default is a version of Xalan (which only supports XSLT 1.0). There is no guarantee that this will always be true of every Java VM in the future.*

I'd consider this answer an argument against the Java way of doing things.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your last statement? I thought this was a good way of specifying the implementation to use.

Comment: @kjp - It's verbose, confusing, and redundant. I don't think it's necessary to have so many ways to do it. I've looked this up 100 times and of course I still had to look up the exact syntax again to provide this answer.

Comment: Awesome! Method 2 did not work on Java 7, but it worked if I instantiated the class itself.

Comment: It should still be supported in Java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html

Comment: dear lwburk what should be the parameter 'YourApp' in java -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=
        cnet.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl YourApp

Comment: The app you're starting

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly construct the required `Source` and `Result` objects to make sure they are Saxon implementations rather than whatever the default ones are.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I do that?

Comment: See the comment of Michael Kay. Normally you use the "standard" API classes but these are free to return "any implementation" that conforms to the API. However, you explicitly want to have SAXON implementations so the best bet is to poor over the SAXON docs and figure out which classes implement the StaX API concepts of Source, Result etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a wrapper around Saxon parser in order to make its use simple, and I called it "[EasySaxon](http://easysaxon.sblendorio.eu)": you can find it [here](http://easysaxon.sblendorio.eu), with some code snippet of samples.

Hope it helps.

Francesco