# Ant Build getting UTF-8 Java Run Time Error

Tags: java, eclipse, utf-8, ant, saxon

I am running an Ant Build in Eclipse Oxygen and am getting this error:

```
[xslt] Warning:  The encoding 'UTF-8' is not supported by the Java runtime.
[xslt] Warning: encoding "UTF-8" not supported, using UTF-8
BUILD FAILED
```

I have tried multiple JREs. Currently I am on jre1.8.0_91.

Is this really a Java error? Is this a configuration error?

Comment: The same question is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177242/the-encoding-utf-8-is-not-supported-by-the-java-runtime, and although I'm not sure any of the answers is very satisfactory, you might find that they give you extra insights.  Googling for "is not supported by the Java runtime" (with the quotes) leads you to further instances, but none of those I followed gave a clear solution.

Comment: This post: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/PLUG-610 traces it to  a version of Xalan, which suggests you're not running Saxon as your keywords suggest you are.